# R Logic For assigning HH Travel Surveys

Tags: r

I am trying to make a logical statement that would arrange the tours of a household. 
A Tour by definition is a series of trips that would start at home and end at home. In this dataset Triptype gives you the infomration. 1=Home 2-5 are non home trips. I want to be able to create a tour number for each sample number and perno (person#). There can be more than one person in a HH who has totally different trips than the other perno. So for sampno 1032558 there is only 1 person in the HH and his tour #1 is 1-4-4-5-4-4-1. I inluded a link to the whole data set if it would help but I just need help with having a loop that could create a new column for Tour# based off of the Sampno, Perno, and Triptype so that the Tour# will be smart enought to know that it needs to reset the count of the tour number based on the change in sampno id, and perno since they would be a different person and HH.

[Data From Household Travel Survey](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mfDEMtY3tTTuUd3RfFcEL4M4-zmUaj_g/view)

```
sampno|perno|tripno|plano|Trip Type
1032558 1   NA  1   1             
1032558 1   1   2   4
1032558 1   2   3   4
1032558 1   3   4   5
1032558 1   4   5   4
1032558 1   5   6   4
1032558 1   6   7   1
1033660 1   NA  1   1
1033660 1   NA  1   1
1033660 1   NA  1   1
1034462 1   NA  1   1
1034462 2   NA  1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider randomly generating a number by grouping in `by`. The anonymous function uses `tryCatch` for `by` slices that have no records which can be the case for more than one factor. Be sure to use a sufficiently high number like `1:10000` to accommodate your data groupings.

```
df_list <- by(tourdf, tourdf[c("sampno", "perno", "triptype")], function(sub) {      
  sub$tour_number <- tryCatch({
      set.seed(sub$sampno[1] + sub$perno[1] + sub$triptype[1])
      sample(1:10000, 1, replace=TRUE)
  }, error = function(e) return(NA))

  return(sub)      
})

new_tourdf <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

new_tourdf
#     sampno perno tripno plano triptype tour_number
# 1  1032558     1     NA     1        1         111
# 2  1032558     1      6     7        1         111
# 3  1033660     1     NA     1        1        1561
# 4  1033660     1     NA     1        1        1561
# 5  1033660     1     NA     1        1        1561
# 6  1034462     1     NA     1        1        8855
# 7  1034462     2     NA     1        1        5636
# 8  1032558     1      1     2        4        1727
# 9  1032558     1      2     3        4        1727
# 10 1032558     1      4     5        4        1727
# 11 1032558     1      5     6        4        1727
# 12 1032558     1      3     4        5         804
```